# I'm getting "Too much recursion" error in angular

Tags: angular, recursion

I am getting "InternalError:too much recursion error" in my angular project. However, I'm unable to find out coz of what I'm getting this error... Is there any way to find out from I'm getting this error... Please help I'm stuck here badly...

PS: There is no code to reproduce since I don't know what is causing the error.

Comment: You have an angular project.  There has to be some sort of code in order to get some sort of Internal Error.   Without providing any details, it's difficult, if not impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PS: There is no code to reproduce since I don't know what is causing
> the error.

You obviously have plenty of code.  The challenge is to find out *which* part of your code is causing the "infinite recursion".

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Comment out parts of your code until you've identified the culprit (or at least identified the module that contains or -invokes - the offending code).

... OR ...

2. Create a new, small test project.  Add code from your "real project" until you successfully reproduce the problem

... OR ...

3. Set some breakpoints, and single-step through the code. This is straightforward with IDEs like Visual Studio code. It shouldn't take long to find the place where your app fails.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try to find out with your suggestions.  I'll get back soon...

Comment: I have got the solution: I was importing the page module recursively. While trying to comment out the sections and going through the code I found out. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution: I was importing the page module recursively. While trying to comment out the sections and going through the code I found out. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Glad it's working.   Please consider posting the relevant code, before and after you fixed the problem.  Showing the details might help somebody else with a similar issue. Please feel free to "upvote" and/or "accept" my response.